# Unable to match data with regular Expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a written a piece of code which accepts an input from the user and inserts it into the Data Base. The HTML code is as follows:

```
<td align="center"><textarea class="txt" required=required rows="3" name="Xschool" cols="30"></textarea></td>
```

And I need to check the data whether is has any special symbols. I used Regular Expression for it and is as follows:

```
    $Xschool=$_POST['Xschool'];
    $pattern = '/[A-Z ]+$/';
$Xschool=strtoupper($Xschool);

if(!preg_match($pattern,$Xschool))
{
    echo "<pre>We are sorry. The X School ".$Xschool." is  invalid. Make sure your name contains no special symbols/numbers.</pre>";
    exit;
}
```

This code works correctly for many types of inputs but is not working for the input `ST MARY'S`. When a ' symbol is encountered the code doesn't work well. What should I do to overcome this? Please help me!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the pattern to: `'/[A-Z\' ]+$/'` ? :)

Comment: Add the quote to the regex as a valid symbol... And add a starting anchor (`^`) to the regex as well.

Comment: If `'` is valid input, why not add it to your regex?!

Comment: NO, { ' } is not a valid symbol. If I give an input as { ST MARY'S } , my code should give an error that, it doesn't accept special symbols, but I am not getting any error. So I tried to insert in DB, but there's an SQL EROR. I don't want { ' } as valid input. @Sumurai8

Comment: That is **absolutely the wrong way to avoid SQL errors**. Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: @user2644795 Can you explain _why_ you don't want an apostrophe to be valid input? Is it just that you're unsure how to make it insert into the database properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something wrong with your basic understanding.

/[A-Z ]+$/

will match any string that contains a line ending in A-Z or space.

I suggest that you want:

```
if(preg_match('/[^A-Z ]/', $Xschool))
{
 ...
}
```

Which will match any string containing a char that is not A-Z or space.

Comment: This is the right answer to the specific question but is NOT the right way to avoid SQL injection attacks - and `St Mary's` seems like it _should_ be a valid school name but you're rejecting it as your system can't handle it. Learn about parameterised queries and avoid this issue altogether

Comment: Uh, yeah. Nobody said anything about SQL injection attacks, although obviously this method would be outstanding in that capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Change the pattern so that it meets your needs. For that, you first need a very clear understanding about what your needs are. `'/[A-Z ]+$/'` did not meet your needs; will `'/[A-Z\' ]+$/'` meet your needs? What about accents? What about characters outside latin-based alphabets? Answer these questions for yourself, then design a regular expression or other validation algorithm based on your answers.

Comment: My valid input is only CAPITAL LETTERS. I should reject all those symbols/numbers other than letters. So my Regular Expression satisfies it. My problem is , it is not showing any error if I use a text as "ST MARY'S ". I should get an error for this. @oswald

Comment: If your valid input is only CAPITAL LETTERS, then why is there a space in the `[A-Z ]` group? If you want only capital letters from the latin alphabet, use `/^[A-Z]*$/`. Please consider what I said about a *very clear understanding about what your needs are*.

Comment: I am sorry. Now I'll explain you. My code should accept an input from the user which could be only letters and can use spaces. I am going to convert the data into uppercase and match with the regex '/[A-Z ]+$/'. When I give an input like "Sravan" it is accepting(this is what I want), "St Mary'" it is showing an error (this is too what I want), but when I give input as "St Mary's " it should throw an error but it isn't.

Comment: That's because the `S` after the `'` matches your regular expression. The `^` in my regular expression from 25 minutes ago prevents that by matching the start of the string. To also allow spaces, use `/^[A-Z ]*$/`. BTW, what do you call the thing that Şebnem Ferah has at the start of her first name? Is that a capital letter, too? If it is, that make things a lot more complicated.

Comment: Yes now I got it. Thanks for the answer and I'll change my code @oswald

Answer (score 0):

Simply include the ' in the match:

```
    $Xschool=$_POST['Xschool'];
    $pattern = "/[A-Z ']+$/";
$Xschool=strtoupper($Xschool);

if(!preg_match($pattern,$Xschool))
{
    echo "<pre>We are sorry. The X School ".$Xschool." is  invalid. Make sure your name contains no special symbols/numbers.</pre>";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: NO, { ' } is not a valid symbol. If I give an input as { ST MARY'S } , my code should give an error that, it doesn't accept special symbols, but I am not getting any error. So I tried to insert in DB, but there's an SQL EROR. I don't want { ' } as valid input. @ivan

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regular expressions.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\'\s]{0,50}
```

this will allow small & capital character and 0 to 9 digit up to 50 name in length.

If you want to use only capital word then.

```
[A-Z\'\s]{0,50}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $Xschool=$_POST['Xschool'];
$pattern = '/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*$/';
$Xschool=strtoupper($Xschool);

if(!preg_match($pattern,$Xschool))
{
    echo "<pre>We are sorry. The X School ".$Xschool." is  invalid. Make sure your name contains no special symbols/numbers.</pre>";
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern, `/[A-Z ]+$/`, does not include a *starting anchor*. That means when you try to match it against `ST MARY'S`, it matches the ending `S` and your code doesn't see any errors. Changing the pattern to `/^[A-Z ]+$/` will fix that problem.

However, based on your comments you have a much bigger problem - you are blindly passing user input to the SQL query without sanitizing it, which means you are **vulnerable to** [**SQL injection attacks**](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Learn the right way to defend against these attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) instead of coming up with misguided bandaids like this regex.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I will make it out. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

Replace all VALID characters, in your scenario the A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,SPACE and any other VALID character with nothing "". Then, if the remaining string has length > 0 that means some other INVALID character must exist.

```
<?php

    function isStringOnlyAZSPACE($the_string)
    {
        $valid_chars = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',' ');

        $the_string  = str_replace($valid_chars, "", $the_string);

        return (strlen($the_string)==0);
    }

    echo isStringOnlyAZSPACE("ST MARY'S")?"true":"false"; // FALSE

    echo isStringOnlyAZSPACE("ST MARYS")?"true":"false"; // TRUE

?>
```

see it in action here http://3v4l.org/GvVi6

i must also repeat the comment from @DCoder in your question "That is absolutely the wrong way to avoid SQL errors."